# NOT condition not working in solr

Tags: solr

I am no Korean expert and am finding it difficult to fix this, searching for the following query, but the NOT condition doesn't seem to be working.

```
 (stnostem:((옵티머스 OR "엘지 스마트폰") AND NOT ("옵티머스 프라임" OR 프라임)))
```

the search result return result with the NOT condition keywords? How can this be fixed.

Regards,
Ayush

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the `-` to specify a pure negative query. Try the following:

```
 stnostem:(옵티머스 OR "엘지 스마트폰") -stnostem:("옵티머스 프라임" OR 프라임)
```

You may need the AND between the two queries depending upon what your DefaultQueryOperator is.

Comment: Updated to specify the field for the negative query from http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html

Comment: Nope not working, actually for English it seems to be working fine but not for korean.